# PHP mysql query loop to get lowest value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row

I need to create loop, get lowest ID value from mysql.

So I tried this script:

```
<?php
include "configuration.php"; // mysql konfiguration
$jungiam = mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
mysql_select_db($db_name, $jungiam);
$darom = mysql_query("SELECT * from task where id = (
        SELECT 
            MIN(id)
        FROM
            task)");
$rez = mysql_num_rows($darom);
while ($rez > 1) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($darom); 
echo $komanda = $row['komanda'];
mysql_query('DELETE * FROM task WHERE komanda = ' .$row['komanda'].'');
}
return true;
?>
```

I need to get lowest id and print to page `$row['komanda']`, after printing delete from that table where `komanda = $row['komanda']` (printed text).

After deleting record, I need to do script from the start, so it will print text  with lowest id from mysql and after that text will be deleted and proccess will start from start and will be repeating until all records in table 'task' will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * from task ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;"
```

This will return the first element with the lowest ID.